# Hide Chart.js bubble points based on filtering

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using Chart.js 2.5.0 and wondered if anyone could give me some pointers on the following functionality requirement.

I have a bubble chart that for arguments sake contains tweets.

I have a list view next to the chart that display the tweets. Connected to this is the ability to filter, so it will only display tweets with specific string value the user inputs.

What I would like to do is when the user utilities the filter, it only shows the bubbles corresponding to the filtered result. I am passing the `pointIndex` and the `datSetIndex` into my table. However, I am really struggling in working out how to update the chart so it hides the bubbles that are not matching the current filter output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far? (A JSFiddle would be nice too.)

Comment: Hi after a bit more digging I have something working in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prmw1bm2/12/

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt solve my entire issue as Im using Vue which seems to be causing issues with updating the chart. However if you are using plain chart.js the blow fiddle gives one way to hide specific or all points

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/prmw1bm2/12`
```

it may help someone somewhere